# Capturing an IP Address in to a variable in a script

Tags: batch-file, ip

I have found some amazing answers about how to capture my computers IP address in a script but all of the answers have the user output the IP address immediately.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%f in ('ping -4 -n 1 www.google.com ^|find /i "pinging"') do echo IP=%%f
```

I have a particular need to be able to use the IP Address later in the script.  How can I store it in a variable for later use?  I would think it would be something line the following:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%f in ('ping -4 -n 1 %COMPUTERNAME% ^| find /i "pinging"') do set /A IPADDR=%%f
echo IP: %IPADDR%
```

When I do this, the variable only contains the first octet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use the arithmetic option `/a` for the `set` command.  set "IPADDR=%%~f"

Comment: @DavidRuhmann should add an answer and Courtney should accept it

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the arithmetic option `/a` for the `set` command. `set "IPADDR=%%~f"`

*Comment moved into answer.*